# Get back initial content of array

Tags: javascript

I just have some function wich deletes elements from array,is there any way to get initial content of array when there are no elements in it ?
i know i have to use

```
if(array.length=0){
}
```

but it beats me what to put inside the curly braces.I've tried to create an array which duplicate the first one,and then after implementing the function assigning my empty array to the duplicated one,but it didn't work

Comment: What are the contents of the array *if* there are no elements in it?

Comment: If there are no elements in the array there is no content... right?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you mean by initial value?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use the single `=`. Use `===`  instead. `=` assigns a value to a variable, and `===` makes a comparison.

Comment: I use if/else statement . it seems something like if(array.indexOf(el)>-1&&array.length>0){ array.splice(index,1)}else{here i should somehow restore the value of array}

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do this define var on top of

```
 function var car ="";
 if(array.length =0){
// do your operation cars = new Array("Saab", "Volvo", "BMW")
  enter code here;
 }`
// you can get get data console.log(cars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var copyOfArray = array.slice(0); //Returns a copy of all the elements in array

if(!array.length){
    array = copyOfArray.slice(0);
}
```

If you array includes objects you use the following method to get the values only (not functions):

```
var clonedArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nodesArray));
```

Comment: I tried that, but it seems that while the first array is changing ,assigning one is changing as well, and at the end of function they both empty

Comment: Sorry about that. I just fixed my response.

Comment: It seems like this works! There is only one problem left,but that's is off-topic a little bit,thank's a lot anyway)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a copy of an array you need to do a so called deep copy.

```
var a = [11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99];
var a_copy = a;
var a_backup = [];
console.log("original length = "  + a.length)
for(var i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
  a_backup[i] = a[i];
}
for(var i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
  a[i] = undefined;
}
console.log("original = "  + a.join(","))
console.log("copy     = "  + a_copy.join(","))
console.log("backup   = "  + a_backup.join(","))
console.log("original length now = "  + a.length)
for(var i = 0;i<a_backup.length;i++){
  a[i] = a_backup[i];
}
console.log("restored = "  + a.join(","))
```

It also depends on how you deleted the entries. If you did as I did the length stays the same but there are other methods that change the length of the array itself, you need to check that.